# Quick method to find cross index between two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Lets say that I have a 2 dimensional array such as:

```
x=array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

And another holding the same values but in a different order and size perhaps, such as:

```
y=array([[4,5,6],[1,2,3],[7,8,9],[1,2,3]])
```

I would like a quick method using no dictionaries or lists 
(already done that) to find the index locations of y with respect to x. 
So the output would be:

```
z=array([1,0,2,0])
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Make It Work, Make It Beautiful, Make It Fast.` So first we have to find solution, then we will look for faster code

Comment: I think `np.array_equal` would do by iteration over both arrays